# how shall i validate json against schema

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose

hi i am using MEAN STACK i want to validate JSON keys that comes from front end against mongoose schema. I am validating values but how shall i validate keys that com from client side  for example.

```
var CategorySchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
        default: '',
        trim: true,
        unique: [true, 'Category name already exists'],
        required: [true, 'Category Name cannot be blank'],
        minlength: [4, 'Minimum 4 characters required'],
        maxlength: [12, 'Category name cannot be That long']
    },
    parentCategory: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
        default: '',
        trim: true,
        required: [true, 'description cannot be blank'],
        minlength: [10, 'Very short description']
    },
    imageUrl: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    }
});
```

what if i am providing this format

```
{

  "IMAGEURL": "c:\abc.png",         instead of imageUrl
  "DESCRIPTION": "here is some description", INSTEAD OF description
  "PARENTCATEGORY": "Men Wear", instead of parentcategory
  "Name": "Shirts" instead of name
}
```

i am writing rest api that will be authenticated is it necessary to check these things. kindly help

Comment: i want serverside validation of json in node

Comment: 11 months later: I suppose [JSON schema](http://json-schema.org/) is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

For me json schema is so complicated. I suggest to use [Json Pattern Validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jpv)

```
npm install jpv
```

it is very simple to use without any additional keys, and has many patterns to describe json.

```
import jpv from 'jpv';

var json = {
  status : 'OK',
  data : {
    url : 'http://example.com'
  }
}

var pattern = {
  status : /^OK$/,
  data : {
    url : "[url]" 
  }
}

console.log( jpv.validate(json, pattern ) )
```